# Found wrong Inheritance and Interface on Partial Classes

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, odata

I am using the inheritance and Interfaces concepts in my partial classes and my 1 class which is partial is inherited from an Interface but I found the typecasting error on this: 
My interface class ImedicalGroup.cs

```
public partial interface IMedicalGroup : IAudit
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Child partial class medicalgroups.cs

```
 public partial class MedicalGroups : IMedicalGroup,IAudit
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
#Audit region
}
```

My 2nd partial class of medicalgroups.cs in QueryableDbContext.cs

```
[global::System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKeyAttribute("Id")]
public partial class MedicalGroups
{
....
}
```

But I have found error on this line is `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'HRBC.BusinessDataContext.MedicalGroups' to 'HRBC.Domain.Entities.IMedicalGroup'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"`

```
IMedicalGroup IClient.MedicalGroup { get { return MedicalGroup; } }
```

Comment: Carefully check, for each `partial` part of a class or interface, just which `namespace` declaration it resides in. I think you have created *two* distinct types with name same name in distinct namespaces when in fact you wanted *one* type with `partial` declarations. Also check that all parts are in the same "program" (same C# project, not just same solution). Otherwise, again, you will get distinct types instead of having the parts compiled together into one class/interface.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes both resides on different solutions but i have another class carrier... and my medical group class is ditto copy off carrier but my carrier class works fine???

Comment: If the above code was really compiled, clearly *one* type `MedicalGroups` would be implicitly convertible to *one* interface called `IMedicalGroup`. Note that each "program" (C# project) can only create one non-nested type with a given name and number of type parameters *in each namespace*. So first check that the namespaces from the error text you quoted are exactly like you expect. Check that it is the namespaces you wrote in the code. Then check if different assemblies (C# projects) define types with name clashes. Use "Go to definition". And check that all projects were re-compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Are you sure your interface needs to be partial?
2. If you implement `IMedicalGroup`, you don't need to specify `IAudit` too, since `IMedicalGroup` already forces you to implement `IAudit`
3. Make sure, that your child partial classes are in the same namespace! ( namespace X.Y.Z { ... })!

Cheers! :)